# Missing QGIS python plugin database connectors

Tags: python, qgis, plugins

I am working with python plugins for QGIS.I developed my plugin and inorder to incooperate the same into QGIS i copied the folder in

```
C:\Documents and Settings\comp90\.qgis\python\plugins
```

I opened my **QGIS** exe and installed the same.It is shown under **Databases-->PG & SL.
My code is as follows:

```
SUPPORTED_CONNECTORS = {'postgis':'1.5', 'spatialite':'1.6'}
MISSED_CONNECTORS = []

def listDatabases(self):

    actionsDb = {}
    actions = DbConnection.ConnectionManager.getAvailableConnections()


    for a in actions:
        actionsDb[ unicode(a.text()) ] = a


    return actionsDb

def getAvailableConnections(self, conntypes=None):

    if conntypes == None:

        conntypes = ConnectionManager.SUPPORTED_CONNECTORS.keys()
    if not hasattr(conntypes, '__iter__'):
        conntypes = [conntypes]

    connections = []
    for c in conntypes:
        connection = self.getConnection( c )
        connections.extend( connection.getAvailableConnections() )
    return connections

def getAvailableConnections(self):
    connections = []

    settings = QSettings()
    settings.beginGroup( "/%s/connections" % self.getSettingsKey() )
    keys = settings.childGroups()
    for name in keys:
        connections.append( Connection.ConnectionAction(name, self.getTypeName()) )
    settings.endGroup()

    return connections
```

but the **actionsDb** is blank.In **QGIS**, the connection is established. When I try to open the plugin in QGIS ,it does not open because **actionsDb** is blank. What can be the problem??

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you having trouble with RT Sql Layer or with your own plugin?

Comment: For this kind of problems try also the qgis-developer mailing list.

Comment: @underdark---With my own plugins....

Comment: I don't think we can help without seeing your code.